# How to replace route parameters in active route

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have the following route

```
{
    path: ':teamId/sample',
    component: SampleComponent
}
```

Let's say I'm currently at the route `10/sample`, How can I navigate using the Router to `x/sample` where the value `x` is obtained dynamically (observable subscription, etc).

If I have to replace query params for the active URL I would simply do

```
this.router.navigate([], {
    queryParams: { // updated params },
    queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
});
```

but how to achieve the same with Route params?

**EDIT:** I have a bunch of such routes and the route param isn't always the first part of the route, It can be even be like `/xyz/abc/:teamId/foo`, I am looking for a generic solution which also handles such cases.

#### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nv93df?file=src/app/sample/sample.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
this.randomNumberService.data$.subscribe(random => {
  const snaphsot = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.pathFromRoot;

  this.router.navigate(snaphsot.slice(1).map(s => {
    if (s.routeConfig.path === ':teamId') {
      return random;
    }
    return s.url.join('/');
  }), {preserveQueryParams: true})
});
```

**Important to note:**

For this solution you have to configure the `':teamId'` path as it's own segement, like:

```
{
    path: ':teamId',
    children: [
      {path: 'after', component: SampleComponent}
    ]
  },
```

Otherwise the check `s.routeConfig.path === ':teamId'` will resolve to false.

#### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsjsll?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsample%2Fsample.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I wasn't clear with my question, the route param won't always be the first part of the url, it could also be something like /xyz/abc/:teamId/sample. I don't know what the previous part of the URL will be. I am looking for a more generic answer which works with all cases

Comment: Ok, I understand. But you know the route "xyz/abc" or whatever routes, which are before ":teamId/sample"? Or are they generic too?

Comment: I just know that the route param is in the middle of the active URL, it can contain sub routes both after and before the param, I guess the route somehow needs to be reconstructed using the router service.

Comment: I'm getting closer to figure out your problem :D But wouldn't it be easier to resolve this via a queryParam? Or is this a no-go?

Comment: Yeah I have considered using query params but unfortunately I cannot use them. The values aren't optional and are required in multiple components.

Comment: Could you validate this Stackblitz for me? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsjsll?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsample%2Fsample.component.ts

Comment: It's an interesting solution, if the route has query params it's not preserved but I'll handle that problem, this works for me. Thanks!!

Comment: Perfect! For the queryParams just add {preserveQueryParams: true} as second argument to navigate and you should be fine.